# I don't know why I cannot import the .ods file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx, xlrd, ods

I cannot use Python package "xlrd".

I wanted to deal with an excel data and prepared ods file and save in the directory where there is this python's file.
I was trying to import an ods file, but an error below occurred.

Python code

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("lung.ods")
```

ERROR

```
 In [21]: runfile('/home/****/Desktop/working/survival10.py', wdir='/home/****/Desktop/working')
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-21-7a27e6491452>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/home/****/Desktop/working/survival10.py', wdir='/home/****/Desktop/working')

File "/home/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/****/Desktop/working/survival10.py", line 16, in <module>
book = xlrd.open_workbook("lung.xlsx")

File "/home/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 150, in open_workbook
raise XLRDError('Openoffice.org ODS file; not supported') # in the xlsx's case

XLRDError: Openoffice.org ODS file; not supported
```

Then I changed the file from ods type to xlsx type and coded this.

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("lung.xlsx")
```

but the same error occurred.
The file's pass is "/home/****/Desktop/working"

I'm using Anaconda3, Python 3.6 and the module "xlrd" has already been installed.

Please tell me what the problem is with this.

Comment: 1. Reading the documentation on a library is *essential*; xlrd reads "... data from Excel spreadsheets (.xls and .xlsx, versions 2.0 onwards)" and it does not mention .ODS *anywhere*. 2.  Your wording "I changed the file from ods type to xlsx type" strongly suggests that you did so by *renaming the file*. Am I correct in that?

Comment: ods format is **not** an Excel file...

Comment: Thank you for kind answers. Since then I've been trying to do something.

I imported the raw data as the csv file without renaming or I changed the file style. But I couldn't use "xlrd" package. I heard that recently many people have used "pandas" as you know instead of "xlrd" when they wanna import csv or xlrd files. So I gave up using xlrd and started using pandas, then I made it.

I'm afraid that what the problem was about my "xlrd" problem remain unknown.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a nice option using Pandas, a great way to deal with tabular data.

Just install the `odfpy` and `pandas` packages (with `pip install ...` or etc) and then use Pandas' `read_excel()` function with the `engine='odf'` option. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('lung.ods', engine='odf')
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#opendocument-spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

The *.ods* suffix indicates that your spreadsheet file was created with *OpenOffice* or *LibreOffice*.

You have two options:

Either you open the file in *OpenOffice/LibreOffice*, **but save it as an *Excel* file (*Save As..*)**. Afterwards you should be able to handle the saved-as file with *xlrd*.

Or, instead of using *xlrd*, you look for a Python package that can handle *.ods* files. You might want to search https://pypi.org/.